# Building same Image for multiple machines using conf file

Tags: yocto, glibc, bitbake, riscv

I want to build an image for 2 different machines i.e. rv64ima and rv64imafd with the help of Yocto but the recipes are common for both . Is there any way that I can change the input flags for respective machines in their machine configuration file. So that the only parameter I should pass is the name of machine.

Comment: If you have two different machines and want to set a variable in a recipe differently, you can do: `VARIABLE_rv64ima = "something"` or `VARIABLE_append_rv64ima = " something"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set MACHINE variable from the outside. In your layer.conf file you can set default machine like:

```
MACHINE ?= "rv64ima"
```

And in bash or your bash script you set MACHINE variable implicitly:

```
export MACHINE="rv64imafd"
```

Similar question you can find [heir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684816/yocto-bitbake-configuration-for-machine-variable-via-shell-environment-variable).

Comment: @Anaadi Mishra, if you need any additional info on this subject I'll add to my answer, just let me know. If it clearly answers your question, could you please mark it accepted? Thanks